# UDF to display string as hexcode

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have some strange characters in a VARCHAR field which prevent me from converting the field into an INTEGER. I want to debug this and so I need an UDF that will convert the string to a hexadecimal code (just like in a hex editor) so that I can see which characters I am dealing with.

Where can I find such a function or how can I write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple casting to varbinary would do the trick.

```
select cast( @string as varbinary(max))
```

Answer (score -3):

**And** if you implement `RULE` and `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` in the, um, database, you can prevent strange characters getting into your fields in the first place.  It is in the manual.